# SEO and domain name - which shape?

Tags: seo, domains, domain-registration

I just want to register the domain name for my spanish class and wonder, what domain name is beter for this purpose:

- learningspanish.com
  or
- ilearnspanish.com

Which one is better? The domain name must be English, but I don't know, what is better for Google and SEO - if **learn** or **learning**...

I would be grateful for your feedback and sorry if the explanation above is not understandable (I would try to explain it better).

Thank you

Comment: I like learningspanish.com better but yes they are already taken

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, both domains are already taken.

Also, I wouldn't burn too many calories on this. Even if the other one was free, they are both relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Google recently rolled out a new update, where Exact Match Domain are not a bonus anymore (apparently). A lot is yet to be tested on this, but it looks like EDM lost all their power. Go for the domain that sounds better from a branding point of view.